# How to compute Data table row is in double type and based on other fields in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application my data table is

```
            DataTable dtTemp = dt.Copy();
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("Timee", typeof(double));
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("Taskk", typeof(string));
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("Countt", typeof(string));
```

I need to compute `Timee` column based on `Month and Taskk`
Here I tried
 `var sum11 = dtTemp.Compute("Sum(Timee)", "Month='May' and Taskk='1'");`

I tried with this in LINQ also i need to filters the rows here i am taking single row i need to filter with two rows

```
var result = dtTemp.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Taskk") == "1")
                    .Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x["Timee"]));
```

but i am not getting anything anyone one please help me out

Thank you

Comment: try doing a `Select()` first, using the same filter. See if u get any rows.

Comment: @dotNET, Hi, could you please tell me how to take this

Comment: Can you show all or some of the data? Is it possible the contents of the Taskk filed are padded with spaces to a fixed length - so need trimming.

Comment: Hi, I need to take Month and Task for filters records in LINQ how can i take that `var result = dtTemp.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Taskk") == "1")//and Month also
                    .Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x["Timee"]));`